# Packet Tracer cannot send pdu from lan to wireless

Tags: networking, network-programming, cisco

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8VLH.png)

I can't send pdu from pc to wireless laptop

Answer (score 0):

It actually can send the PDU because u only have a network so the network between your PCs and your laptops is actually the same network. Check your IP address on your PC (it should be on the same network / subnet). If your PCs and laptops are already on the same subnet, check the port of the connected cable on the wireless router. It should be placed on ethernet / gigaethernet. But u can't connect it into internet port.
 
The wireless router that u are using is actually only Access Point. Because of that, it only can have a single network either on LAN or wireless.

Hope it helps!